# OpenGTS 2.6.0 Configuration for TK103 Protocol device

Tags: opengts

Device Communication server TK10x is not receiving data from remote device!
How to debug?
Where to look for troubleshooting?
CentOS 7 server, OpenGTS 2.6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a huge variety of reasons:

- Errors port settings.
- firewal is blocking the port.
- other software uses the same port.
- AVL device is misconfigured.
- DCS is not running or was not executed improperly.
  ... and much more..

check the DCS configuration file at:

```
%GTS_HOME/dcservers_release.xml
```

look the DCS TK10x log file at:

```
 %GTS_HOME/log/tk10x.log
```

check the port status (31272 as default port for tk10x)

```
 ss -tp | grep 31272
```

if you are really sure that packets do not reach the DCS .
verify the settings would be appropriate in the AVL.
and the port on the server is accessible from the outside.

Comment: Thanks TronSoft for your solution... firewall was blocking the port.